# What does this perl malware do with changing "$0"?

Tags: perl, cracking

We had an intrusion into our server over the weekend and I'm trying to trace the tracks of the intruder. It seems they ran a perl script, causing a www-data process called `init` to run at 100%. Unfortunately I don't have perl expertise, so I have no clue what this is doing:

```
 6 my $processo =("atd","sendmail: accepting connections","rpc.idmapd","syslogd -m 0","/sbin/udevd -d","/sbin/init");
# ...
24 use IO::Socket;
25 use Socket;
26 use IO::Select;
27 chdir("/tmp");
28 $servidor="$ARGV[0]" if $ARGV[0];
29 $0="$processo"."\0"x16;;
30 my $pid=fork;
31 exit if $pid;
```

It seems to me the instruction in line 29 is intended to hide the process somehow. What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> On some (but not all) operating systems assigning to `$0` modifies the argument area that the `ps` program sees. On some platforms you may
>   have to use special `ps` options or a different `ps` to see the changes.
>   Modifying the `$0` is more useful as a way of indicating the current
>   program state than it is for hiding the program you're running.

So yes, your assertion is correct. It's looking to mask how it shows up in `ps`.

Comment: So, since I'm seeing a very suspicious process with the name `init [3]` would it be possible that this is it? I'm not sure about the `$processo` variable and how it influences `$0`.

Comment: If you see any processes named init that are not a) process ID #1 and/or b) owned by root... then they are not the real "init" process.  "init" is always process ID 1 and owned by root.

Comment: @TimPeoples: The thing is, I'm seeing both an `/sbin/init` process and an `init [3]` process, both run by `www-data`. Both look suspicious to me.

Comment: I'd assume those are bogus.  Again, "init" is always process ID 1 and is always owned by "root".  ALWAYS. I recommend you kill those other ones.

Answer (score 3):

This line appears to be intentionally obfuscated:

```
my $processo =("atd","sendmail: accepting connections","rpc.idmapd","syslogd -m 0","/sbin/udevd -d","/sbin/init");
```

It is equivalent to:

```
my $processo = "/sbin/init";
```

Comment: does it make any difference with multiple `"\0"` termination?

Comment: So, is this the same as the C comma-operator?

Comment: @mpapec: I suspect the null-termination is meant to hide command line arguments from `ps` et al.

Comment: @bitmask it may be, although on my debian box it doesn't `perl -e '$0="processo"."\0"x16; print qx(ps auxw|grep $$)'`

Comment: Note: the reason this assignment works as described above is because, in Perl, the value of a list on scalar context is the last element of the list.  (also note that a "list" is not an "array"; the value of an "array" in scalar context is the number of elements in the array).  In the above, there's a literal list and thus, all the other elements are discarded when assigning to `$processo`.